Bound over the volume of connected components of the sphere split in two by an affine hyperplane.
This problem was already solved on the site for low dimensional cases, but I would like an answer for the general case.
Context: Let $d \geq 1$, $\mathbb{D}^{d+1}$ the $d+1$-dimensional unit disk, $\mathbb S^d$ the $d$-dimensional unit sphere, $H$ and hyperplane and $v \in \mathbb{B}^{d+1}$ defining $\mathcal H = H + v$ an affine hyperplane.
We set $V = C_d \sqrt{1- \|v\|^2_2}^d$ the volume of the intersection $\mathcal H \cap \mathbb B^{d+1}$ and $S_0 \sqcup S_1 = \mathbb{S}^d \setminus \mathcal H$ the connected components and $m = \min (\operatorname{vol} S_0, \operatorname{vol} S_1)$.

Here $C_d$ is the volume of the $d$-dimension disk.

Now is there a way to find bounds of the form
$$m \leq f(V)$$
and
$$V \leq g(m)$$
?
In my mind this is undeniable but I'm not very good at Riemannian geometry and ask chatgpt to work with curvature is too much ;)
Probably this bound will at least be polynomial (I hope) and depending on the curvature of the sphere but I feel like I lack some background to treat the problem.
